# Regarding the connectedness of the Long Line

Tags: general-topology

I'm having the Devil's own time with wrapping my head around connectedness WRT the Long Line. 1st let me give my understanding of the Long Line - if I am incorrect then the question needs to be reexamined.   I believe that the Long Line is a mapping from the real line to the real line such that each point on the Long Line represents a copy of the real line. Is this correct? If it is then how does one show that the line is connected?
Here's my definition from Munkres' "Topology 2nd Edition": a Topological Space X is said to be locally connected at x∈X if "every neighborhood of x contains a connected neighborhood of x". That is given V is a neighborhood of x there is a connected set U⊆X (which is not necessarily open in X) and a subset W⊆U such that W is open in X and x∈W⊆U⊆V.
So far so good, but how is the Long Line in any way locally connected? Between every point on this line is an entire real line (from negative infinity to positive infinity), so how does a body get from any one point to the next? The next point is > infinity away so I don't see how to make limits to work. It seems to me that there is a discontinuity between each point, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Am I being silly here?

Comment: "I believe that the Long Line is a mapping from the real line to the real line such that each point on the Long Line represents a copy of the real line. Is this correct?" No, it doesn't make sense. You can construct a sort of "long line" by replacing each point in the real line by a copy of the whole line - essentially $\mathbb R^2$ with the lexigraphical order - but usually the term is used for a different space obtained by filling in the gaps in $\omega_1$ with copies of $\mathbb R$. Decide exactly how to define the topology on your long line; only then can you investigate its properties.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here; what the long line is, how to interpret topological properties, and how to visualize spaces built from other spaces. I'll try to touch on each issue rather compactly (:P).

---

First, let's talk about what the long line is(n't). You write:

> I believe that the Long Line is a mapping from the real line to the real line such that each point on the Long Line represents a copy of the real line.

This doesn't quite parse for me, but it sounds like you're talking about a particular topology on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ - thought of as replacing each point in $\mathbb{R}$ by its own copy of $\mathbb{R}$. (Technically: the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) on the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on $\mathbb{R}^2$.) Note that this is quite different from the *usual* topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If so, that's **incorrect**. The long line is built from two very differently-flavored pieces: the real line $\mathbb{R}$, or more accurately the interval $[0,1]$, and the [**first uncountable ordinal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) $\omega_1$ (some texts, like Munkres, denote this by "$\Omega$"). Despite each being order topologies, they're quite different. In particular:

> There is no increasing map from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

*(This is a good challenge exercise - think about the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Note that this exercise will only make sense after you understand $\omega_1$, and that's not easy when you first see it: it's a rather technical object, and you'll need to spend some time parsing it.)*

This is where the "long" in "long line" comes from: even though in terms of *cardinality* we have that $\omega_1$ is at most as big as $\mathbb{R}$, there is a geometric sense in which $\omega_1$ is bigger than $\mathbb{R}$. In jargon, $\omega_1$ has bigger **cofinality** than $\mathbb{R}$.

The long line, then, is intuitively gotten by replacing each point in $\omega_1$ (not $\mathbb{R}$) by a copy of $[0,1]$, and "stitching them together" appropriately. Most obviously we'll want to "glue $0$s an $1$s together:" the $1$ of the $\alpha$th block will be identified with the $0$ of the $\alpha+1$th block. Things are a bit more interesting at *limit* ordinals. I'm not going to go into the details here - you should carefully read the definition of the space in your text - but it might be helpful to visualize the first $\omega+1$-many blocks, glued together, as looking like $$[0,{1\over 2}]\cup[{1\over 2},{2\over 3}]\cup[{2\over 3}, {3\over 4}]\cup[{3\over 4},{4\over 5}]\cup ...\cup [1,2].$$

---

OK, now on to connectedness. I'm going to focus on $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ - the lexicographic topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ - rather than the long line itself, since I think it will be easier to understand the long line after you understand $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ and already with $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ there are several issues.

The big one is a **distance** issue: when you say

> $>$ infinity away

or

> how does a body get from any one point to the next?

(ignoring the fact that there is no such thing as a "next point" in even $\mathbb{R}$ itself), you're implicitly thinking in terms of far/near and motion in the sense that we're familiar with. That doesn't make sense in a general topological space: topology is all about what we can do with *just* the concept of openness and its derived notions *(like closedness, compactness, etc.)*. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic, but that means that topologically seaking there is a real line between $0$ and $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ - even though $\mathbb{R}$ is connected! Connectedness (even *path*-connectedness) does not mean "you can get there from here," it just means what it says in its technical definition.

There's also a point/set confusion going on here, I think: a point in $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ is a **pair** $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Think of this as saying "the $b$th point in box $a$" - the boxes themselves are *not* points. In particular, even if we think about the "boxes" as being far apart - which per the above we shouldn't - there are still lots of points "in the same box." Each box is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ basically by definition, and each box is open in $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ *(this is a good exercise: use the definition of the order topology carefully, and think about how $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-n,n)$)*, so $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ **is locally connected**: each point lives in an open set (its "house") which is connected as a subspace of the whole. On the other hand, that same fact that each "house" is open means that the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ is disconnected: consider "all the points in house $0$" vs. "all the points not in house $0$" (= "all the points in some other house").

---

Overall, you need to be more careful with the definitions. Don't try to leap ahead and instantly guess what the various spaces look like or mean; go slowly through their precise definitions and read them as they are. As a specific habit which might be useful, I recommend explicitly writing out yourself what the points and (basic) open sets in a given space are - even if your book has all this explicitly written down, re-writing it yourself will force you to see passages you might have passed over accidentally otherwise.

(As to the long line: yes, it **is** connected, basically because unlike with $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ we've "joined the houses without gaps." Once you understand why $\mathbb{R}^2_{lex}$ is locally connected but not connected, this will be easier to parse.)

Comment: Do you mean $\omega_1 \times [0, 1]$, or $\omega_1 \times [0, 1)$?

Comment: @BrianTung That's where the "stitching them together" comes from: I'm taking the underlying set of the long line to be a *quotient of* $\omega_1\times[0,1]$ since in my experience that's a bit more concrete. Doing $\omega_1\times[0,1)$ is more efficient, but I think a little more mysterious. (Although of course this is subjective.)

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the clear response! So, there are "only" ω1 copies of (0, 1). I made so many mistakes. When you tell me that R = ⋃n∈N(−n,n), it looks like a great example of an open cover for R (is this correct?) so you opened my mind about that topic as well (never understood open covers well before this). Sorry for the confusion. I'm an old guy with a grounding in (up to) multi-variate calculus and linear algebra I who is trying to teach himself topology because I think it is beautiful.

Comment: I'm going to finish reading Munkres - and doing the probs - and I'll probably be back with some more questions in a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: @Spanki Glad to help! Yes, $\{(-n,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (or similar) is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$, and a very important one - it's the standard example of an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ with no *finite subcover*. This is a rather technical condition - I'm not sure you've already seen it - but it winds up being important: spaces in which every open cover has a finite subcover are called **compact**, and compactness turns out to be a super useful property. The example above shows that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact; however, it turns out that the closed unit interval is (this takes a hard proof).